# Confidence interval using percentile and computed manually giving different results

Tags: confidence-interval, quantiles

I am doing data science course from datacamp and not very clear about confidence intervals.

> Length of `nohitter_times` is 251.
>
> Draw bootstrap replicates of the mean no-hitter time (equal to tau):

```
bs_replicates
bs_replicates = draw_bs_reps(nohitter_times,np.mean,10000)
```

> Compute the 95% confidence interval: `conf_int`

```
conf_int = np.percentile(bs_replicates,[2.5,97.5])
```

> Print the confidence interval

```
print('95% confidence interval =', conf_int, 'games')
```

> Plot the histogram of the replicates

```
_ = plt.hist(bs_replicates, bins=50, normed=True)
_ = plt.xlabel(r'$\tau$ (games)')
_ = plt.ylabel('PDF')
```

> Show the plot

```
plt.show()
```

Output:

> 95% confidence interval = [660.67280876 871.63077689] games

Now I try to match confidence interval generated by above code manually by the formula given [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/confidence-interval.html):

Formula:    $$X  \pm  Z \cdot \frac s {\sqrt(n)}$$

$X$ is the mean
$Z$ is the chosen Z-value from the table above (1.960)
$s$ is the standard deviation
$n$ is the number of samples

```
X = np.mean(bs_replicates)
Z = 1.960
s = np.std(bs_replicates)
n = 100 - square root of 10000
```

I get $763.212765737051 \pm 1.041230771.$

Why manually calculating and using formula  `[660.67280876 871.63077689]` generating different results?

Please suggest or guide to a resource which can be helpful.
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

$n\;$ is $\;251$, the number of values in your original data. You've put in the number of bootstrap replicates, which is the wrong value.